# Calling method on initial start up only

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make sure that a method is called *only* on the initial start up of the app. This means that it won't be called if you switch between apps or re-navigate to the main activity. It *should* be called if the process is terminated and ran again.

I've tried setting a `Boolean` for the MainActivity's `onCreate` method, but it seems that gets reset when navigating to another activity and coming back.

I tried using `onSaveInstanceState`, but it seems that isn't working either:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(!mInitBool) {
        myMethod();
        mInitBool = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("initBool", mInitBool);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mInitBool = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("initBool");

}
```

`myMethod()` is still being called every time the Activity is loaded.

What is the best way of handling this sort of call?

Comment: In this case you can use Application class http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Application.html or SharedPreferances http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html  where you can put your boolean value

Comment: Won't those persist across multiple instances of the application? If they quit the application and start it again, I'm needing the method to be run again on that start up as well -- just not EVERY time the MainActivity is created.

Comment: have you tried making `mInitBool` `static`?

Comment: You can put your boolean variable as static in application class first set it as false after calling your method set true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.mypackage;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    initMethod();
}

public void initMethod(){
    //do something here
}
```

}

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml add the following:

```
<application
    android:name=".mypackage.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This registers an Application class **that get's called and instantiated only once when the application starts**. Do your work in the initMethod, and this is your easiest solution. Your MainActivity can be created over and over again, but this class is only created once, and method only called once (until application is closed by you or the device's OS)

Note that the package name is important to have a '.' before it in the manifest

Comment: Does the application declaration in the manifest have to be a new `<application>` element, or should I add the `android:name` key to my existing one?

Comment: add it to the existing one :) easy as that

Comment: your app has only one application element, and by creating this one as I suggested, you are simply just creating a custom one to suit your applications need. The purpose of this, most of the time, is to handle state events and update activities based on new states. This is because the application class has access to all activities

Comment: I named my new Application class `applicationStart` and edited the manifest file. On start up, the app crashes saying it cannot cast `applicationStart` to type `MainActivity`. Do I have to do any shuffling around to make it compatible with my existing application?

Comment: add to your question what you added exactly so i can debug it

Comment: Nevermind, I was doing something stupid! I think this method will work fine, now I just need to find out how to get a reference to the `MainActivity` from this Application class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the hard way but u can put the filter("RUN") in Android Device monitor and see it does what u want

It loads boolean onCreate , when your method run it will save to true so your method wont be called after renavigate and when u finish(); it will save back to false so your method will run when u launch your app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private SharedPreferences Preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor;


private boolean mInitBool;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Preferences = getSharedPreferences("myBool", MODE_PRIVATE);
    PrefsEditor = Preferences.edit();

    Log.e("onCreate", "RUN");
    mInitBool = Preferences.getBoolean("mInitBool", false);

    if(!mInitBool) {

        myMethod();
        Log.e("!mInitBool", "RUN");
        PrefsEditor.putBoolean("mInitBool", true);
        PrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}

public void myMethod(){

    Log.e("MyMethod", "RUN");
}

public  void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

   PrefsEditor.putBoolean("mInitBool", false);
   PrefsEditor.commit();

}
```